# Ldap error when try to runserver, Django/Python

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, ldap

[image]I can't seem to find much information about my topic online so I figured I'll ask. I'm trying to set up an app on Django and when I try to 'runserver' I get the following error. It runs with no problem when I remove the ldap configurations but when I add it back in I get this error. Anyone have an idea what can be causing this to break? I'm using Ubunut 20.04 on a windows machine.[image: Ldap error message]

Comment: You should show us how you set up your **ldap** in your python file

Comment: Did you follow exactly how the official docs do  https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: I've added my ldap configs

Comment: Okay it's working fine ?